# Unable to install powerline module

Tags: python-3.x, vim

I wanted to install powerline for vim so did 'pip install powerline' to install the module. But the terminal gave me an error.

Tried searching for the issue but got no good result.

The terminal output is as follows:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-06bn015i/powerline/setup.py", line 27
        zip_safe = False,
        ^
    SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the wrong Pip project for the statusline / prompt utility.
Use `pip install powerline-status` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`zip_safe` keyword is repeated 2 times in `setup.py`.

The code seems to be too ancient. Last release was in 2008. The code was hosted at Google Code, now in archive mode. You better find a more modern code.

Comment: Yes. You can download an archive, unpack, edit `setup.py` and run `pip install .` But I'm sure for such ancient code you need Python 2.

Comment: Hi, could you explain what setup.py is? And I the location for setip.py given on the terminal screen is not a valid one

Comment: It's a file in source code. Download the sources from https://pypi.org/project/powerline/#files